# Where is the function cssyyparse code in webkit project?

Tags: c++, functions

Recently, I have viewed webkit source code and there is a function 'cssyyparse' which I cannot find c++ body code.
Ther is only declaration of function cssyyparse.

```
// CSSParser.cpp
extern int cssyyparse(WebCore::CSSParser*);
...
cssyyparse(this);
```

But, I can't find body of code in whole of WebKit source code.
How can I find cssyyparse function code? Is there something wrong with me?

source::
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp?format=txt

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a reverse engineering question, so you might get better results on stack overflow. However, `yyparse` is a function name normally generated by the `yacc`/`bison` parsers. You might want to look for a grammar definition in a `*.y` file.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit uses [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for parsing. You can find the grammar files here:

- [/Source/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y.in](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y.in)
- [/Source/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y.includes](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y.includes)

The default Bison parsing function name is `yyparse`. WebKit uses a preprocessor written in Perl to automate a few things, including changing the function prefix to `cssyy`. The preprocessor is in [/Source/WebCore/css/makegrammar.pl](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/makegrammar.pl).